# Compute column means for numerical columns of R data frame, show default value for non-numeric columns

Tags: r

For an R data frame where all the columns are numeric, I can use colMeans to compute column means. Is there a way in R to recognize which columns are non-numeric and set those column means to some default value such as -999? The data looks like this:

```
  sym   mkt_ret  NAV_ret     diff  premium      mkt      NAV    mkt_time    nav_time
 NRGX    -3.31    -0.25     -3.06    -4.16     7.60     7.93 04-27@16:02 04-27@20:01
  PCI    -2.31     0.36     -2.67     3.46    17.36    16.78 04-27@16:02 04-27@20:01
  PDI     0.28     0.34     -0.06    11.95    23.24    20.76 04-27@16:02 04-27@20:01
```

For the code

```
infile = "table.txt"
xx = read.table(infile,header=TRUE)
print(xx)
print(colMeans(xx,na.rm=TRUE))
```

I get an error

```
Error in colMeans(xx, na.rm = TRUE) : 'x' must be numeric
Calls: print -> colMeans
Execution halted
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, some columns are not numeric, if we remove those columns by indexing, it should work

```
i1 <- sapply(xx, is.numeric) # create a logical vector for numeric columns
out <- setNames(rep(-999, ncol(xx)), names(xx)) # initialize a vector with -999
out[i1] <- colMeans(xx[i1], na.rm = TRUE) # assign the colMeans to update

out
#      sym    mkt_ret    NAV_ret       diff    premium        mkt        NAV   mkt_time   nav_time 
#-999.00000   -1.78000    0.15000   -1.93000    3.75000   16.06667   15.15667 -999.00000 -999.00000
```

---

With `tidyverse`, we can use `summarise_if`

```
library(dplyr)
xx %>%
     summarise_if(is.numeric, mean, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Or change non-numeric column values to `-999` and then use either `summarise_all` or `colMeans`

```
library(purrr)
xx %>%
   mutate_if(negate(is.numeric), ~ -999) %>%
   colMeans(na.rm = TRUE)
#       sym    mkt_ret    NAV_ret       diff    premium        mkt        NAV   mkt_time   nav_time 
#-999.00000   -1.78000    0.15000   -1.93000    3.75000   16.06667   15.15667 -999.00000 -999.00000
```

---

Or another option is `lapply` and pass a `if/else` function

```
sapply(xx, function(x) if(is.numeric(x)) mean(x,  na.rm = TRUE) else -999)
```

---

Also, if we use `mean` instead of `colMeans`, it would still work by generating NA for those columns having non-numeric values (there would be a warning message though)

```
sapply(xx, mean)
#   sym  mkt_ret  NAV_ret     diff  premium      mkt      NAV mkt_time nav_time 
#     NA -1.78000  0.15000 -1.93000  3.75000 16.06667 15.15667       NA       NA
```

#### data

```
xx <- structure(list(sym = c("NRGX", "PCI", "PDI"), mkt_ret = c(-3.31, 
-2.31, 0.28), NAV_ret = c(-0.25, 0.36, 0.34), diff = c(-3.06, 
-2.67, -0.06), premium = c(-4.16, 3.46, 11.95), mkt = c(7.6, 
17.36, 23.24), NAV = c(7.93, 16.78, 20.76), mkt_time = c("04-27@16:02", 
"04-27@16:02", "04-27@16:02"), nav_time = c("04-27@20:01", "04-27@20:01", 
"04-27@20:01")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem, also the code below may help too.

```
data("mtcars")
mtcars$X1 <- factor(mtcars$gear, levels = c(4,3,5)); str(mtcars) #create an non numeric column X1
my.mean <- function(x){ if(is.numeric(x)) c(mean(x), median(x))} 
my.df <- setNames(as.data.frame(unlist(lapply(mtcars, FUN = my.mean))), "values"); my.df
my.df$names <- rep(c("mean","median"), times = length(row.names(my.df))/2); my.df
my.df$variables <-  rownames(my.df); my.df
library(stringr)
my.df$variables <- str_remove(my.df$variables, "[12]"); my.df 

data_wide <- spread(my.df,  names, values)
data_wide

> data_wide
   variables       mean  median
1         am   0.406250   0.000
2       carb   2.812500   2.000
3        cyl   6.187500   6.000
4       disp 230.721875 196.300
5       drat   3.596563   3.695
6       gear   3.687500   4.000
7         hp 146.687500 123.000
8        mpg  20.090625  19.200
9       qsec  17.848750  17.710
10        vs   0.437500   0.000
11        wt   3.217250   3.325
```